# JNI Assertion Failed

Tags: java, opencv, java-native-interface

I was assigned to do some application with a tight deadline. In order to complete it in time, I made a choice to use Java, as I'm more experienced at it than C++ (I needed to use OpenCV library).

Everything went fine and I almost finished my application, except I'm missing a line that uses applyColorMap function from OpenCV, when I noticed that it doesn't exist on OpenCV Java. Since I've been working with wrappers for a while (from C++ to C# using Unmanaged Wrappers) I decided to wrap by myself that function, but It gives me Assertion Failed [image: Assertion Failed].

Here's my code Java Code:

```
public class CVPlusNative{

    public static native void applyColorMapN(long srcAddr, long dstAddr, int colorMap);
}

public class CVPlus {

    public final static int COLORMAP_AUTUMN = 0;
    public final static int COLORMAP_BONE = 1;
    public final static int COLORMAP_JET = 2;
    public final static int COLORMAP_WINTER = 3;
    public final static int COLORMAP_RAINBOW = 4;
    public final static int COLORMAP_OCEAN = 5;
    public final static int COLORMAP_SUMMER = 6;
    public final static int COLORMAP_SPRING = 7;
    public final static int COLORMAP_COOL = 8;
    public final static int COLORMAP_HSV = 9;
    public final static int COLORMAP_PINK = 10;
    public final static int COLORMAP_HOT = 11;

    public static void applyColorMap(Mat src, Mat dst, int colorMap)
    {
        applyColorMapN(src.nativeObj, dst.nativeObj, colorMap);
    }
}
```

Here's my C++ code:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_nativelibrary_CVPlusNative_applyColorMapN(JNIEnv *env, jclass thisClass, jlong srcAddr, jlong dstAddr, jint colorMap)
{
    cv::applyColorMap(*(cv::Mat*)srcAddr, *(cv::Mat*)dstAddr,  (int)colorMap);
}
```

Now here's the weird part: If the provided source and destination are not the same object, it works fine, but if they are it gives me that error. I tried to use that function in C++ and it works great even when the two provided objects are the same, but for some reason my wrapper doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the two provided objects are allowed to be the same? It doesn't seem to say that in the documentation, but it does say the destination will be created (which presumably overwrites the source, if they're the same object).

Comment: Yes' I'm absolutely sure. I've already tested that function in C++ code (done a simple program) and it worked fine.

Comment: In C++, "works fine" and "always works" are two different things

Comment: It always works. I've been using OpenCV for the past 3 years.